# how to render a roman number symbol in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax

this tex [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513444/195238)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[ p(h|\mathcal{D})=
\frac{p(h|\mathcal{D})p(h)}{\sum_{h'\in\mathcal{H}} p(h'|\mathcal{D})}=
\frac{p(h)\mathbb{I}(\mathcal{D}\in h)/|h|^N}{%
\sum_{h'\in\mathcal{H}} p(h')\mathbb{I}(\mathcal{D}\in h')/|h'|^N}
\]
\end{document}
```

generates this roman numbers symbol

[image]

running the same code in jupyter notebook gets this

[image]

how to render a roman number symbol in jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\mathbb{I}` is *not* a roman numeral II, it is a blackboard bold capital I.  Use `\mathrm{II}` for upright roman numeral II (or if you really don't want any space between them `\mathrm{I\!I}`.

You *should* get the same symbol in Jupyter, but it may be that there is a problem with the font.